# Error in Migrate from sql server to Mongodb: Specified cast is not valid

Tags: sql-server-2008, mongodb, database-migration

Hi am new to migrating database from SQL server to mongodb. For this am using tool SQL2Mongo http://sql2mongo.codeplex.com/. am having 2 bak file which have backup-ed from sqlserver. am success in migrating one bak file from sql server to mongodb using sql2mongo tool. but for another file am getting an error "**Specified cast is not valid**".I am googled this error its because of not proper bak file or some data misses when backup-ing the bak file.

I want to make sure error is the error only from bak file.

Is any one know how to resolve this error or is there any other tool for migrating sqlserver to mongo db.

thanks in advance.